# Set editor as dirty in Moodle via js

Tags: javascript, moodle

I am working on an advanced grading plugin and have added a button to the grading screen, that changes the content of the (atto) editor via .setHTML in js.
However, pressing the save button afterwards will not save any changes due to moodle not detecting that the content of the editor has been changed.
Is there a way to set the dirty flag on the editor in the grading screen, preferably with js?
Thanks.

My testing environment uses Moodle 4.1.1+.

```
var editor = Y.one('#id_assignfeedbackcomments_editor' + 'editable');
editor.setHTML(comment);
```

Edit: I did not get it to work with the atto editor. However, I am able to do it with TinyMCE now and since [russel england](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1603711/russell-england) pointed out that atto will be removed, I will let the client know that atto is depricated and keep it as a bug for now.

My code currently looks like this:

```
try {
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(comment);
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setDirty(true);
} catch (error) {
    Y.one('#id_assignfeedbackcomments_editoreditable').setHTML(comment);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `EditorPlugin` class, then call this method

```
this.markUpdated();
```

https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/plugintypes/atto#yuisrcbutton

Also note that Moodle will filter and remove some HTML content. Maybe manually enter the html to see if it saves.

Also for reference, the Atto editor will probably be removed in Moodle 4.6

The default editor is now TinyMCE

Developer documentation : https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/plugintypes/tiny

Admin documentation : https://docs.moodle.org/403/en/TinyMCE_editor

Comment: Thanks. I hope comment is the right response, since i am new.  
Since in my setting, writing a editorplugin is not an option, I just added a simple Button to the grading page, which is not connected to the editor. Is it possible to get a reference to the editor class in js, so I would be able to call functions like markUpdated()?  
The setHTML sets the content of the atto editor correctly, it will just not be saved if nothing else is changed on that page. With TinyMCE I was not able to find the right way to enter the iframe yet, but I will have to do that when atto will be removed.